# Order Topology Example

Tags: general-topology

Topology by Munkres says,

> The set $X= \{1,2\}\times \mathbb{Z}_+$ in dictionary order is another example of ordered set with smallest element. Denoting $1\times n$ by $a_n$ and $2\times n$ by $b_n$ we can represent $X$ by $$a_1, a_2,\dots ; b_1, b_2, \dots$$
>
> The order topology on $X$ is **not discrete topology**. Most one-point sets are open, **but there is an exception $-$ the one-point set $\{b_1 \}$**. Any open set containing $b_1$ must contain the basis element about $b_1$ (by definition), and **any basis element containing $b_1$ contains point of the $a_i$ sequence**.

I did not understand why **"any basis element containing $b_1$ contains point of the $a_i$ sequence"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis element containing $b_1$ is an open interval $(c,d)$ where $c<b_1<d$.  We thus must have $c=a_n$ for some $n$.  In that case, we have $a_{n+1}>a_n=c$ and $a_{n+1}<b_1<d$ so $a_{n+1}$ is also an element of $(c,d)$.  Thus the interval $(c,d)$ contains a point of the $a_i$ sequence, namely $a_{n+1}$.

(Actually, there is one more possibility, which is that $c$ might be $-\infty$.  I'll let you figure out how to handle that case.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: It does need it.  If you don't include $-\infty$ as a possible endpoint, for instance, there would be no basic sets containing $a_1$, so it's not actually a basis.

Comment: Ah, of course, missed that.